# Snowflake Replace to joins with group by clause with single join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to take the LATEST CLICK as the latest date for that ID where the Event_Type is click. And do the similar thing for Event_Type = 'open'. I have the data like :

| Id | Event_Type | SRC_CREATED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | click | 2021-04-10 01:50:08.490 |
| 1 | click | 2021-03-10 02:221:05.115 |
| 1 | open | 2021-06-10 01:12:08.288 |
| 1 | click | 2021-08-10 01:50:08.490 |

Outcome required :

| Id | Event_Type | SRC_CREATED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | click | 2021-08-10 01:50:08.490 |
| 1 | open | 2021-06-10 01:12:08.288 |

I have used the query mentioned below, which is working fine, but I want to replace the 2 somehow joins used with a single join to fetch both these data. Can anyone think of a workaround query for that?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE table CUSTOMER AS
select CONCAT(NVL(ADD1,''),NVL(ADD2,'')) AS ADDRESS,
    CASE
WHEN NVL(GENDER,'')='F' THEN 'Female'
WHEN NVL(GENDER,'')='M' THEN 'Male'
WHEN NVL(GENDER,'')='U' Then 'Other'
ELSE ''
END AS GENDER,
***CLICK AS LAST_CLICK,
OPENS AS LAST_EMAIL_CLICK,***
B.PHONE AS PHONE,
A.SRC_CREATED AS SINCE,
from "HXP_SANDBOX"."BASE_RA_TEST"."IDENTITY" A
inner join "HXP_SANDBOX"."BASE_RA_TEST"."EMAIL_INTERACTIONS" B
on A.DIGITALID = B.DIGITALID 
***inner JOIN (SELECT DIGITALID,MAX(SRC_CREATED) CLICK
 from "HXP_SANDBOX"."BASE_RA_TEST"."EMAIL_INTERACTIONS" t
  where EVENT_TYPE = 'click'
 group by DIGITALID) C
on A.DIGITALID = C.DIGITALID
inner JOIN (SELECT DIGITALID,MAX(SRC_CREATED) OPENS
 from "HXP_SANDBOX"."BASE_RA_TEST"."EMAIL_INTERACTIONS" t
  where EVENT_TYPE = 'open'
 group by DIGITALID) D
on A.DIGITALID = D.DIGITALID;***
```

Comment: Used SQL syntax claims that the tag [mysql] is not applicable. Removed.

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL Server when you say its Snowflake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do the following, where you use a `CASE` inside the `MAX` to restrict it to the event types you want.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE CUSTOMER
AS
SELECT CONCAT(NVL(ADD1,''), NVL(ADD2,'')) AS [ADDRESS]
    , CASE
        WHEN NVL(GENDER,'')='F' THEN 'Female'
        WHEN NVL(GENDER,'')='M' THEN 'Male'
        WHEN NVL(GENDER,'')='U' Then 'Other'
        ELSE ''
    END AS GENDER
    , C.CLICK AS LAST_CLICK
    , C.OPENS AS LAST_EMAIL_CLICK
    , B.PHONE AS PHONE
    , A.SRC_CREATED AS SINCE
FROM "HXP_SANDBOX"."BASE_RA_TEST"."IDENTITY" A
INNER JOIN "HXP_SANDBOX"."BASE_RA_TEST"."EMAIL_INTERACTIONS" B ON A.DIGITALID = B.DIGITALID 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DIGITALID
      , MAX(CASE WHEN EVENT_TYPE = 'click' THEN SRC_CREATED ELSE NULL END) CLICK
      , MAX(CASE WHEN EVENT_TYPE = 'open' THEN SRC_CREATED ELSE NULL END) OPENS
    FROM "HXP_SANDBOX"."BASE_RA_TEST"."EMAIL_INTERACTIONS" t
    GROUP BY DIGITALID
) C ON A.DIGITALID = C.DIGITALID;
```

Answer (score 1):

with this CTE to provide data

```
    SELECT column1 as id, column2 as event_type, to_timestamp(column3) as src_created
    FROM VALUES
    (1,'click','2021-04-10 01:50:08'),
    (1,'click','2021-03-10 02:21:05'),
    (1,'open','2021-06-10 01:12:08'),
    (1,'click','2021-08-10 01:50:08')
)
```

the following SQL gives the answers you want:

```
SELECT
    id
    ,event_type 
    ,max(src_created)
FROM fake_data
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

which gives:

| ID | EVENT_TYPE | MAX(SRC_CREATED) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | click | 2021-08-10 01:50:08.000 |
| 1 | open | 2021-06-10 01:12:08.000 |

*BUT* what you asked for is not what your SQL does, and Dale's answer shows how to do that.

Which is the the same in my example data as:

```
SELECT
    id
    ,max(iff(event_type='click', src_created, null)) as last_click
    ,max(iff(event_type='open', src_created, null)) as last_click
FROM fake_data
GROUP BY 1
```

you can use CASE or IFF, I prefer the IFF as it's shorter and explicit. If you are going to CASE path, you can drop the `ELSE NULL` as that is the default behavior.

Thus Dale's example can be:

```
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN event_type = 'click' THEN src_createdEND) AS click
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN event_type = 'open' THEN src_createdEND) AS opens
``
```